# How to ensure execution of time consuming task on reboot/shutdown?

Tags: bash, unix, reboot

I have a bash script that is supposed to execute on reboot/shutdown of a remote Ubuntu server, connected over SSH:

```
ls /etc/rc{0,6}.d/k99*
/etc/rc0.d/k99_stop_all  /etc/rc6.d/k99_stop_all
```

The script needs about 3 min to finish.

How can I ensure the reboot/shutdown only happens on successful execution of `k99_stop_all`?

Does `sudo shutdown -r 10` starts execution of the script scheduled for reboot?